# ASP.NET Web API 2 re-routing

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I am building a restful services for my data using ASP.NET web api 2.

In the data model, I have an entity called "ServiceProvider" which provide "Service"(s).

so, I am building restful for those two entities.
the requirements is to build two restful services, one as follow

```
api/serviceProvider/{id}/services
```

which gives list of services provided by that provider.

as well, the requirements is to give the same data (services by provider) through this rest service

```
api/services?serviceProviderId={providerId}
```

so, I created two controllers, for "serviceProvider", and for "Service"
I already implemented the second call, by creating an action method in the "Service" controller with this signature

```
public IEnumerable<Service> GetServiceByProvider(int providerId)
```

because both are going to run the same code, can I just re-route the first call to the second one? 
At the same time, not effecting the other actions in both controllers??

I tried to do this is the webApiConfig with no success

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "serviceByProvider",
                           routeTemplate: "api/serviceProvider/{id}/services",
                           defaults: new { controller = "Service", action = "GetServicesByProvider" });
```

where the "GetServiceByProvider" is the method name in the "Service" controller that will serve the second call

but without success

As I said there are other actions in both controllers I don't want to affect them by this routing.
Like I have the following

```
api/serviceProvider
api/serviceProvider/{id}
api/services/
api/services/{id}
.....
```

Answer (score -1):

I decided to try again and duplicate your environment and found a problem in your route template. The parameter your route is expecting is called `id` but your `GetServicesByProvider` method accepts a parameter called `providerId`. The framework is looking for parameters with the same name. Changing this should get your routing working the way you want it to AND maintain all of your previous routes.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "serviceByProvider",
    routeTemplate: "api/serviceProvider/{providerId}/services",
    defaults: new { controller = "Service", action = "GetServicesByProvider" }
);
```

Comment: Sorry jebar, but your solution doesn't work
First of all, the attribute routing doesn't work when you change the controller name.
Like our example, when I add on the service controller, an attribute of ServiceProvider, it doesn't work when there is already a serviceProvider controller.

Comment: Sorry jebar, but your solution doesn't work
First of all, the attribute routing doesn't work when you change the controller name.
Like our example, when I add on the service controller, an attribute of ServiceProvider, it doesn't work when there is already a serviceProvider controller.

Second, for the routing.
Your method is overwriting the default Get of the controller.
Which means if I do the following with your routing:

api/services

Then it is going to go to that action.